# I would like to add another session to the login file

Tags: php, mysql, session

For example currently I'm able to echo the username session once logged in. I would like to be able to echo another session such as 'company' based on the user that's logged in. That information is also located in the members table.

```
<?php
    //include config
    require_once('includes/config.php');

    //check if already logged in move to home page
    if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: dashboard.php'); } 

    //process login form if submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            exit;

        } else {
            $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
        }

    }//end if submit

    //define page title
    $title = 'Login';

    //include header template
    require('layout/header.php'); 
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
                <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                    <h2>Please Login</h2>
                    <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="signup.php">Create an account</a></p>
                    <hr>

                    <?php
                    //check for any errors
                    if(isset($error)){
                        foreach($error as $error){
                            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                        }
                    }

                    if(isset($_GET['action'])){

                        //check the action
                        switch ($_GET['action']) {
                            case 'active':
                                echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Your account is now active you may now log in.</h2>";
                                break;
                            case 'reset':
                                echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Please check your inbox for a reset link.</h2>";
                                break;
                            case 'resetAccount':
                                echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Password changed, you may now login.</h2>";
                                break;
                        }

                    }


                    ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                             <a href='reset.php'>Forgot your Password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    //include header template
    require('layout/footer.php'); 
    ?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest assigning the Session to the userid and then you can fetch all from the userid to echo out other information.

Comment: you realize that this code is totally unsafe to be used inside a live environment. Use a prepared statement and `password_hash()/password_verify()` if you want to keep your data safe and db intact.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Are you seeing something I don't? As far as we know, the `$user->login()`-method might include both prepared statements and password_hash(). Probably not, but it _could_. Echoing `$_POST`-variables without filter them though, that's just begging for XSS attacks + no CSRF protection.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well, I stand to be right but in this case I stand to be 50% wrong ;-) so, we'd be both right *lol* but chances are, it's not safe; *spidey sense*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not disagreeing with you there... :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Seeing `$user->is_logged_in()` suggests they're using Wordpress. It's hard to know what that and other methods hold in store though. Could also be CI.

Comment: @Fred, to be honest, it looks very familiar to an old tutorial I followed when learning PDO, I'll refer to it (as i have the files here for others to learn from (probably not the best idea)) and confirm momentarily.

Comment: @Option It looks like either Wordpress or CI, hard to say really.

Comment: Thanks guys. Those answers helped me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to assign the users session to the user id.

Here is an example:

`$userid = $_SESSION['user_session'];`

with this in place you can then simply: `` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = ? ``

I'd strongly suggest using prepared statements for this as it's so much more practical and effective (and also bind your params (if you're not currently)).

As Fred mentioned above, your code is possibly vulnerable (dependant on your queries and if you have hashed your passwords!!!).

**In the event you're not hashing:**

Your passwords should be encrypted using `password_hash()` upon registering and then `password_verify()` upon logging in etc.